# String.Remove doesn't work

Tags: c#

I have such code and can't understand where is the mistake, despite the fact, that this code pretty easy. So `q` is a full path, and I need to get required path to `Gen_ParamFile`

```
string q = @"C:\ProgramData\RadiolocationQ\script-Data=12^6-12^33.xml";
string _directoryName1 = @"C:\ProgramData\RadiolocationQ";
int Length = _directoryName1.Length + "ascript".Length; 

 string Gen_ParamFile = q;
 Gen_ParamFile.Remove(0, Length); // this line don't  do anything

var Gen_Parfile = Path.Combine(_directoryName1, "GeneralParam-Data" + Gen_ParamFile);
```

I used function like said here http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/9ad138yc(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It does, it just doesn't affect the actual string, it creates a new one as a result. Use:

```
Gen_ParamFile = Gen_ParamFile.Remove(0, Length);
```

Comment: Got it, feel myself like an idiot )

Answer (score 6):

Because [`String.Remove`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.remove%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method returns a new string. It doesn't change original one.

> **Returns a new string** in which a specified number of characters in the
>   current instance beginning at a specified position have been deleted.

Remember, strings are *[immutable types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object)*. You can't change them. Even if you think you change them, you actually create new strings object.

You can assign itself like;

```
Gen_ParamFile = Gen_ParamFile.Remove(0, Length);
```

As an alternative, you can use [`String.SubString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hxthx5h6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method like;

```
Gen_ParamFile = Gen_ParamFile.SubString(Length);
```

Answer (score 2):

defiantly you can use like

Gen_ParamFile = Gen_ParamFile.Remove(0, Length);

apart from that you can also use

String.Substring method according to your requirment